# Requirements for impelemting Zooz in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, payment-gateway

I am new in using payment gateways. I have to use Zooz in my app.

Our client will create an account for Zooz .

Please tell me which things i have to ask from client about Zooz account that i need to use in app. like APP key, is there other parameters also that i need to ask form client? which will be used in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

invoiceRefNumber is your system accounting invoice number, it is for
tracking only and not used by our system.
appKey - is the app key you received from us upon registration

Creating a payment request and opening the payment dialog.

```
-(IBAction)pay{
       ZooZ * zooz = [ZooZ sharedInstance];
       zooz.sandbox = YES;//set this if working in Sandbox mode
       ZooZPaymentRequest * req =
       [zooz createPaymentRequestWithTotal:32.1 invoiceRefNumber:@"1234" delegate:self];
       req.currencyCode = @"USD";
       [zooz openPayment:req forAppKey:@"app_id"];
 }
```

Comment: I know it dear, but i want to ask, does invoiceRefNumbers can be any number ? or it is related to account parameter. i mean it is filled in account information?

Comment: It is the invoice number of the prodcut/service you are providing against the payment, ie you are the one who have to generate and pass.

Comment: so it will not be used in account info right. i need only appkey and bundle id from the client right?

Comment: Yes, appkey and bundle id are the main things, u need to get it from ZooZ.

Comment: Invoice number is like receipt number for the the product you are buying.